# multi-word match in a mysqli string in php

Tags: php, mysql, regex, mysqli

I have a database that looks kind of like the following:

```
ID   |   TEXT
1    | I like to eat cheetos.
2    | There is a snake in my boots
3    | to eat is to like food
4    | The sun stopped setting, Rlyah Cthullhu!
5    | Beat the heat with icecram!
6    | Treat yourself!
7    | Eat at Joes!
```

And I have a mysqli query that looks kind of like the following...

```
SELECT `ID` FROM table WHERE `ID` > 0 AND (`TEXT` REGEXP '/(like)(eat)/');
```

I've also tried it as the following:

```
SELECT `ID` FROM table WHERE `ID` > 0 AND (`TEXT` REGEXP '/^(^like|^eat)/');
SELECT `ID` FROM table WHERE `ID` > 0 AND (`TEXT` REGEXP '(like)(eat)');
SELECT `ID` FROM table WHERE `ID` > 0 AND (`TEXT` REGEXP '/(?=like)(?=eat)/');
```

None of these matched any of the fields (and I have no clue why, as far as I can tell, they should have worked). And out of desperation, I tried...

```
SELECT `ID` FROM table WHERE `ID` > 0 AND (`TEXT` REGEXP 'like|eat');
```

Which of course being an 'or' instead of an 'and' matching, it matched 1, 3, 5, 6, and 7.

But what I WANT it to match is 1 and 3.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should look into using full text search.

Comment: Try `REGEXP '(\blike\b|\beat\b)')` https://regex101.com/r/dXiJ6Q/1

Comment: perhaps: WHERE text LIKE '%like%' AND text LIKE '%eat%'

Comment: Why would the ID column ever be less than 1? That seems like a very curious restriction.

Comment: @rtfm I'm trying to do it with regex as it's a bit easier to craft the text from an array I'm parsing, otherwise, I'm sure that'd work.

Comment: an easy loop really, but your call

Comment: @tadman it was just a tossaway fill-in bit for another where clause I knew worked that matched most of the fields, just to keep the syntax as close as possible to what I'm actually doing.

Comment: Some reason not to switch to `FULLTEXT`?

Comment: @liljoshu - the usual "tossaway" is `1=1`, which will literally be tossed.  Using `id>0` may cause performance problems due to the Optimizer focusing on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More concisely for "OR":

```
REGEXP '[[:<:]](like|eat)[[:>:]]'
```

For "AND":

```
    REGEXP '[[:<:]]like[[:>:]]'
AND REGEXP '[[:<:]]eat[[:>:]]'
```

But a `FULLTEXT` index (also "AND") would be much faster with

```
MATCH (col) AGAINST ('+like +eat' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the pattern to

```
REGEXP '(\blike\b|\beat\b)')
```

Basically, `(a|b|c)` would match `a` or `b` or `c` *anywhere* in the subject. Adding `\b` (word boundary) before and after each word ensures matches are only produced if a word appears within word boundaries, that is, space, newline or other separator characters.

[In MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#regexp-syntax), however, escaped special characters are replaced with custom markers. For word boundaries, use `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]`

```
REGEXP '([[:<:]]like[[:>:]]|[[:<:]]eat[[:>:]])')
```

https://regex101.com/r/dXiJ6Q/1

Comment: Just tried it, it's returning an empty set too. Also, I'm wanting like AND eat, not just like OR eat. (I'll update the original post to be more clear.) Part of the problem I'm guessing might be something with mysql's interpretation of regex? Because I've tried others that should work but don't.

Comment: Check the regex example. It matches like _and_ eat on the same line but only if they are individual words, not part of another word.

Comment: I did, but it's not matching when I use it in mysql. Also, it needs to only match only if they're both there.

Comment: Sorry, in MySQL, special markers take over escaped control characters in the pattern. See my update.

Comment: Huge improvement! Still need to get it so it needs to match all the variables and not just at least one... going to try it by including the ^ symbols since that might work now.

Comment: Hmm.. not quite. /^([[:<:]]^like[[:>:]]|[[:<:]]^eat[[:>:]]) is returning an empty set...

Comment: Sorry, you are very unclear. What is "all the variables and not just at least one"? This regex now matches all instances of TEXT where the word 'like' or 'eat' appears within word boundaries. You aren't doing great explaining what you need to achieve.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I'm looking to match 'like' AND 'eat', not just 'like' OR 'eat'.

Comment: @liljoshu - what are you expecting for `^`?  And for the leading `/`?

Comment: The leading / was to remove ^ from the beginning so it's not triggering 'start of string', but the alternative meaning of 'removing the following', as NOT (NOT | NOT) is equivalent to "AND" instead of "OR"